# How to detect serial port disconnected in linux guest running on vmware player?

Tags: vmware-player

It seems to me that when running a linux guest on vmware player, if you disconnect the serial port there is no signal or interrupt. Similarly for connecting.  Can anyone confirm this is true or perhaps it is a limitation of the driver I am using (https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport)?

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that when i plugin modem, dmesg showed me that it was detected. maybe you can follow  what dmesg shows and find solution, good luck.